# In Python functions what does a stand alone * in the parameters mean

Tags: python, function-parameter

I am going through the excellent [Python 3 Metaprogramming](http://dabeaz.com/py3meta/index.html) tutorial by [David](http://twitter.com/dabeaz) [Beazley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288810/david-beazley).

In it there is a decorator that looks as follows (slide 50):

```py
from functools import wraps, partial

def debug(func=None, *, prefix=''):
    '''
    Decorator with or without optional arguments
    '''
    if func is None:
        return partial(debug, prefix=prefix)

    msg = prefix + func.__qualname__
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(msg)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

In the parameters of the function there is a * that is between the keyword parameter `func` and `prefix`. I have tested the decorator with or without the star and in both cases it works.

My question is - what if any, is the purpose of the *?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It marks the end of the parameters that may be provided by position only. The arguments following the `*` must be specified as keyword arguments. See [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) for more info.